# Блокирует ли Брендмауэр Net.sockets? C#

Tags: c#, сокет, wcf, firewall

### Вопросы по брендмауэру:

- Существует ли лимит на передачу файлов?  (Вычитал где-то, что
  запрещается передача больших файлов за раз, но "больших" — это
  каких?)
- Имеет ли для него значение какие порты я использую для передачи
  данных? К примеру, какой порт я поставил в TcpListener?
- В общем: при каких обстоятельствах мой socket может заблокировать
  Firewall?

### Остальные вопросы:

- Как обстоят дела с Firewall'ом, если ты используешь WCF?
- Возможно ли просто разблокировать все привилегии для программы в
  Брендмауэре через код?

Comment: Библиотека Net сокетов, на самом деле обвёртка над WinApi библиотекой сокетов. Для неё права не лучше и не хуже чем права для остальных "видов" сокетов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первые 4 вопроса ответ простой - зависит от настроек. Если сетевой администратор истинный параноик, то в сети все будет разрешено только по "белым спискам".

На дефолтных настройках в пользовательских ОС проблем не замечал, на серверных ОС надо смотреть по факту, от версии к версии дефолтные настройки иногда меняются, да и используются редко, сервер все таки.

> Возможно ли просто разблокировать все привилегии для программы в
>   Брендмауэре через код?

**Нет**, во всяком случае точно не "просто", как минимум нужны достаточные привилегии для данной операции и естественно зависит от используемого брандмауэра. Какой смысл в брандмауэре, если любая программа может самостоятельно снять ограничения?

Кое что можно сделать через UPnP, при условии что это разрешено в сети и технология поддерживается всеми заинтересованными участниками.